# jQuery autocomplete fetches UTF-8 (hex) to .php

Tags: php, jquery, encoding

I have an issue with jQuery autocomplete that appears only on actual webhosting (not on my localhost server). The thing is when autocomplete fetches data to .php script (not from .php back to html) it fetches data in UTF-8(hex) format e.g.

> %c4%8d   //instead of letter "č"

After that .php tries to find out sth like "hru%c4%8d" in the database, the result is of course nothing.

I have UTF-8 charset everywhere. I've tried functions mb_convert_encoding,utf8_decode,utf8_encode nothing worked for me.

Here is my code

jQuery autocomplete:

```
$( "#naseptavac" ).autocomplete(
{
    source:'db.php',
    minLength: 2, 
    delay: 1,
    select: function(event, ui)
    {
        $("#naseptavac").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#volba").submit();
    }
})
```

PHP:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
include "connect.php";
mb_convert_encoding($_REQUEST['term'], 'UTF-8');
$req = "SELECT p.znac_id, p.potr_naz, z.znac_naz, k.kat_sekce, k.kat_podsekce
        FROM 
        (potr p
        INNER JOIN seznam z
        ON p.znac_id=z.znac_id)
        INNER JOIN kat k
        ON k.kat_id=p.kat_id
        WHERE p.potr_naz LIKE '%".utf8_decode($_REQUEST['term'])."%' OR z.znac_naz LIKE '%".utf8_decode($_REQUEST['term'])."%'
        ORDER BY p.znac_id ASC, CHAR_LENGTH(p.potr_naz) ASC, p.potr_naz ASC
        LIMIT 0,7";

$query = mysql_query($req);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    if(empty($row['znac_naz']))$row['znac_naz']="";
    $results[] = array( 'label' => $row['potr_naz'],
                        'producer' => $row['znac_naz'],
                        'section' => $row['kat_sekce'],
                        'subsection' => $row['kat_podsekce']);
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

Thanks for reply :)

Comment: I've done provisional fix with str_ireplace by replacing collapsing characters (it is not really a thing I'm proud of)

Comment: Finally found out where the problem was, it's all about redirecting in .htaccess file, really interesting